# How to mount volume in docker compose version '2' format

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, docker, docker-compose

So I have a trouble with mount new format version 2 docker compose file.
I have the code in folder `wordpress` inside where is location `docker-compose` file also I have inside the folder code docker file like this:

```
FROM debian:jessie
VOLUME /var/www/wordpress
```

When I used old format like this:

```
application:
    build: code
    volumes:
        - ./wordpress:/var/www/wordpress
        - ./logs/wordpress:/var/www/wordpress/app/logs
    tty: true
db:
    image: mysql
    ports:
        - 3306:3306
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
        MYSQL_DATABASE: somename
        MYSQL_USER: root
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
php:
    build: php-fpm
    ports:
        - 9001:9001
    volumes_from:
        - application
    links:
        - db
nginx:
    build: nginx
    ports:
        - 8080:80
    links:
        - php
    volumes_from:
        - application
    volumes:
        - ./logs/nginx/:/var/log/nginx
elk:
    image: willdurand/elk
    ports:
        - 81:80
    volumes:
        - ./elk/logstash:/etc/logstash
        - ./elk/logstash/patterns:/opt/logstash/patterns
    volumes_from:
        - application
        - php
        - nginx
```

When I started use version '2' the same as code as previous version I got any error so I reformat my compose file and move `dockerfile` from code folder to insider main folder where is location `docker-compose` file. My new version docker-compose became looks like as:

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    volumes:
     - /wordpress:/var/www/wordpress
     - /logs/wordpress:/var/www/wordpress/app/logs
    tty: true

  db:
      image: mysql
      ports:
          - 3306:3306
      environment:
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
          MYSQL_DATABASE: somename
          MYSQL_USER: root
          MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
  php:
      build: php-fpm
      ports:
          - 9001:9001
      volumes_from:
          - web
      links:
          - db
  nginx:
      build: nginx
      ports:
          - 82:82
      links:
          - php
      volumes_from:
          - web
      volumes:
          - /logs/nginx/:/var/log/nginx
  elk:
      image: willdurand/elk
      ports:
          - 81:80
      volumes:
          - /elk/logstash:/etc/logstash
          - /elk/logstash/patterns:/opt/logstash/patterns
      volumes_from:
          - web
          - php
          - nginx
```

Finally after reformat the code `docker-compose` was successfully build and up but when I open my `php` and `nginx` container inside both of them in /`var/www/worpdress` I have just empty folder app is not my wordpress project.
In which place I was mistake with settings mount project volume?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the way you are defining the local directories to be used for the volumes. In your previous version, you were using `./wordpress`, while in the new one, you're using just `/wordpress`.

When referencing local directories for volume mappings, they always have to start with `./` - please try this:

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - ./wordpress:/var/www/wordpress
      - ./logs/wordpress:/var/www/wordpress/app/logs
```

One more thing: I recommend to always enclose the volume mappings in double quotes to avoid issues with space characters, e.g.:

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - "./wordpress:/var/www/wordpress"
      - "./logs/wordpress:/var/www/wordpress/app/logs"
```